# Include php file according to screen resolution

Tags: javascript, php, include, screen, resolution

First, sorry for my poor english...

I've some troubles with my web page :

I want to load different style according to screen resolution.

I include in my pages the file style.php.

Here is the code :

```
    <?php
if(!isset($_GET['screen_check']))
{
 echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
 <!-- 
 document.location=\"$PHP_SELF?screen_check=done&Width=\"+screen.width+\"&Height=\"+screen.height;
 //-->
 </script>";
}
else 
{    
    if(isset($_GET['Width']) && isset($_GET['Height'])) {
 if(($_GET['Height']/$_GET['Width']) < 0.6) 
 {
 include("stylew.php");
 }
 else {
include("stylen.php");
  }
     }
     else {
     include("stylen.php");
     }
}
?>
```

My problem is, when i load my page, I've an error message display for half a second, wich says : "undefined variable PHP_SELF", and it's kind of awful...But despite it, it works !

I wanted to do something like  :

```
    <script>
if (screen.height / screen.width) < 0.6)
{
   <?php include stylew.php ?>
   }
   else
   {
   <?php include stylen.php ?>
   }
```

To get my variable without reloading my page.
How can I do that ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: PHP runs on the server, before the page is sent to the client. The Javascript doesn't run until PHP is all done. Why not use media queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media Queries would be the best.

With javascript : use jQuery for compatibility in width / height detection.

Like ...

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var newStyle = document.createElement('link');
        newStyle.rel = 'stylesheet';
        newStyle.type = 'text/css';
    if ( ($(window).height() / $(window).width()) < 0.6 ) {
        newStyle.href = 'http://xxx1';
    } else {
        newStyle.href = 'http://xxx2';
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newStyle);
});
</script>
```